# Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal en esta relacion?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

Buenas estoy teniendo un error de relaciones de eloquent según entiendo yo y nose porque.
Es una relación de uno a muchos donde una cuenta/cliente puede tener varios presupuestos, y un presupuesto pertenece a una sola cuenta/cliente. Habiendo explicado esto realicé lo siguiente:

Presupuesto.php:

```
public function cuenta()
    {
        return $this->belongsToOne(Customer::class);
    }
```

Customer.php:

```
public function presupuesto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Presupuesto::class);
    }
```

El error se produce al cargar un presupuesto con el metodo store donde redirige a una vista llamada view-presupuesto.blade.php

```
 public function store(Request $request){
        
        $presupuesto = new Presupuesto();

        $presupuesto->cuenta_id = $request->cuenta_id;
        $presupuesto->formasDePago_id = $request->formasDePago_id;
        $presupuesto->estadosPresupuesto_id = $request->estadosPresupuesto_id;
        $presupuesto->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
        $presupuesto->validez = $request->validez;
        $presupuesto->plazoEntrega = $request->plazoEntrega;
        $presupuesto->lugarDeEntrega = $request->lugarDeEntrega;
        $presupuesto->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('presupuestos.view');
    }
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Call to undefined method App\Model\Presupuesto::belongsToOne() (View: C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\globaltec-vuepanel-master\resources\views\backend\presupuesto\view-presupuesto.blade.php)
```

No estaría entendiendo el error en si, ni que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: `belongsToOne` no existe, el método se llama simplemente `belongsTo`